# Possible sidebar click event conflict

Tags: menu, onclick, sidebar

**Problem**

I am trying to add a collapsing sidebar that slides open when the hamburger is clicked.  The menu works when I remove the form I use to collect the GPS coordinates of the marker

`<form action="">
   <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat">
   <input type="hidden" name="lng" id="lng">`

but when I add the code back to the page, the sidebar doesn't expand.  I believe there is a click event conflict because when I click on the hamburger the map appears to reload but I am unable to locate the issue.  I do not get any errors in Dev Tools.

I tried removing the form coding and the sidebar functions as expected so this is what leads me to believe there is a click event conflict.

**Question**

What would be causing the hamburger click to initiate a map refresh when the form is present?

[Working Page](https://saltwx.com/responsive2.html)

A snippet of my JS

```
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "50%";
}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "0";
}

/* Map Functions */
var map = null;
var layers = [];
var infoBubble;
var content24hr = null;
var content48hr = null;
var content72hr = null;
var content96hr = null;
var content120hr = null;
var airtemp;


function displayMap() {
layers[0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer("https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/kml/marineobs_by_owner.kml", {
preserveViewport: true
});
}


function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
].join(', ');
}

function toggleLayers(i) {
if (layers[i].getMap() == null) {
    layers[i].setMap(map);
} else {
    layers[i].setMap(null);
}
}


function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
].join(', ');
}

function init() {

/* How do we want to set a default location???? */
$("#lat").val(34.6444);
$("#lng").val(-73.580);

var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng($("#lat").val(), $("#lng").val());
var markerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng($("#lat").val(), $("#lng").val());
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 5,
  center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
    });

var icon = {
      url: 'https://static.wixstatic.com/media/e09925_8ec9d5e526f94859b5348b41e3daba74~mv2.png'
    };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: markerPosition,
      title: 'Weather Forecast',
      map: map,
      icon: icon,
      draggable: true
    });
    updateMarkerPosition(latLng);

    infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
    maxWidth: 350
          });

    createTabElements();

    //Set the info bubble items
    infoBubble.addTab('24 Hr', content24hr);
    infoBubble.addTab('48 Hr', content48hr);
    infoBubble.addTab('72 Hr', content72hr);
    infoBubble.addTab('96 Hr', content96hr);
    infoBubble.addTab('120 Hr', content120hr);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      getWeatherForLocation($("#lat").val(), $("#lng").val(), marker);
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
          //Have to close the bubble when we move so we can get new weather info when it stops
          infoBubble.close();
          updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
        });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {

        var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
        var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();

        $("#lat").val(lat);
        $("#lng").val(lng);

        //getWeatherForLocation($("#lat").val(), $("#lng").val(), marker);
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple syntax error on my part.  Working well now.